# Error when calling the metaclass bases: function() argument 1 must be code, not str

Tags: python, class, inheritance, metaclass

I tried to subclass threading.Condition earlier today but it didn't work out. Here is the output of the Python interpreter when I try to subclass the threading.Condition class:

```
>>> import threading
>>> class ThisWontWork(threading.Condition):
...     pass
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    function() argument 1 must be code, not str
```

Can someone explain this error?  Thanks!

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You're getting that exception because, despite its class-like name, `threading.Condition` is a function, and you cannot subclass functions.

```
>>> type(threading.Condition)
<type 'function'>
```

This not-very-helpful error message has been [raised on the Python bugtracker](http://bugs.python.org/issue6829), but it has been marked "won't fix."

Comment: Strange, I didn't think to check its type.  The docs seemt o be a bit misleading then because they say (http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html) "class threading.Condition([lock])" which seems a bit misleading.

Anyway, thanks for clearing this up :).

Comment: I see it as well when mistakenly using a module as a baseclass: class Command(main.cmdroot.list.hosts) rather than the correct Command(main.cmdroot.list.hosts.Command)

Comment: Another common cause is when deriving from a base class which has a decorator. The decorator may change the type of the base class to `type <'function'>` as well.

Comment: Sometimes I accidentally write `def MyClass` instead of `class MyClass`, which then leads to the same error (among others).

Comment: "you cannot subclass functions" - thanks for a definitive answer on this. I wish the error message said THAT.

Answer (score 31):

Different problem than OP had, but you can also get this error if you try to subclass from a module instead of a class (e.g. you try to inherit My.Module instead of My.Module.Class). Kudos to [this post](http://andre.stechert.org/urwhatu/2005/03/typeerror_error.html) for helping me figure this out.

> TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
>
> For this one, the answer is that you probably named a python class the
>   same thing as the module (i.e., the file) that it's in. You then
>   imported the module and attempted to use it like a class. You did this
>   because you, like me, were probably a Java programmer not that long
>   ago :-). The way to fix it is to import the module.class instead of
>   just the module. Or, for sanity's sake, change the name of the class
>   or the module so that it's more obvious what's being imported.

Comment: also when you try to subclass from `def MyClass(object)` instead of from `class MyClass(object)`

Answer (score 29):

With respect to subclassing a module, this is a really easy mistake to make if you have, for example, class Foo defined in a file Foo.py.

When you create a subclass of Foo in a different file, you might accidentally do the following (this is an attempt to subclass a module and will result in an error):

```
import Foo
class SubclassOfFoo(Foo):
```

when you really need to do either:

```
from Foo import Foo
class SubclassOfFoo(Foo):
```

or:

```
import Foo
class SubclassofFoo(Foo.Foo):
```

Comment: this is a great reason not to name your modules like classes :)

Comment: Yup this did it for me, i had the model and the class name the same.

Comment: Can also happen when you type `def` (when you mean `class`) when subclassing, and you're too tired to see it.

Answer (score 2):

Gotten into the same problem.  Finally solved by taking a keen look at the code and this is where the `TypeError` that alarms about a string instead of code comes about..

```
Class Class_name(models.model): //(gives a TypeError of 'str' type)
```

"And"

```
Class Class_name(models.Model): // is the correct one.
```

Notice that specific error comes about because of a single lowercase letter to the code "**Model**" which in turn makes it a string

Comment: "which in turn makes it a string", lowercase words are not automatically strings in python