# why class creation throws error

Tags: python, class

Just playin around class

```
def func(*args, **kwargs):
    print args, kwargs

class Klass(func): pass
```

it throws error

> TypeError: Error when calling the
>   metaclass bases
>       function() argument 1 must be code, not str

What does it mean, i am passing no str nowhere?
and yes I should be passing class in bases but why didn't error say that, instead of this cryptic error?

Comment: The title and most of the question suggests you don't understand why this is happening, but you're really asking why didn't the error message have different text.

Comment: yes I do not understand why it throws such cryptic error, instead of saying "functions can not be class base", i want to know why it is thorwing such cryptic error

Comment: Python throws all kinds of cruddy errors!

Comment: Python3.1 has made the message even less helpful **`TypeError: function() argument 1 must be code, not str`**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see here for the reason for the cryptic msg

http://bugs.python.org/issue6829

questions [Error when calling the metaclass bases: function() argument 1 must be code, not str](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231427/error-when-calling-the-metaclass-bases-function-argument-1-must-be-code-not-s/2231478) has same problem.

**Edit**: play-around

Though you can use metaclass to make it work in a twisted way ;)

```
def func(name, klassDict):
    return type(name, (), klassDict)

class MyMeta(type):
    def __new__(self, name, bases, klassDict):
        return bases[0](name, klassDict)

class Klass(func):
    __metaclass__ = MyMeta

print Klass
```