# How to create a background threaded on interval function call in python?

Tags: python, heartbeat

I am trying to implement a heartbeat call that works in the background. How do I create a threaded on interval call of say every 30 seconds, which calls the following function:

```
self.mqConn.heartbeat_tick()
```

Also how would I stop this thread?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a thread containing a loop

```
from threading import Thread
import time

def background_task():
    while not background_task.cancelled:
        self.mqConn.heartbeat_tick()
        time.sleep(30)
background_task.cancelled = False

t = Thread(target=background_task)
t.start()

background_task.cancelled = True
```

---

Alternatively, you could subclass timer, to make cancelling easy:

```
from threading import Timer

class RepeatingTimer(Timer):
    def run(self):
        while not self.finished.is_set():
            self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
            self.finished.wait(self.interval)


t = RepeatingTimer(30.0, self.mqConn.heartbeat_tick)
t.start() # every 30 seconds, call heartbeat_tick

# later
t.cancel() # cancels execution
```

Comment: It may be important to mention that this *won't* execute every 30 seconds if `heartbeat_tick()` takes a significant amount of time

Comment: Yep, this will be at least 30 seconds every time. At most 30 seconds is a fair bit harder.

Comment: If your foreground function was CPU bound, would the background thread be prevented from ever executing by the GIL?

Comment: @JeffWidman: CPU-bound and "doesn't release the GIL" are not always the same thing. Yes, if the foreground thread held onto the GIL for a minute at a time, then I imagine the background thread would be delayed.

Comment: Thanks @Eric, I did a little more reading on David Beazley's lectures re: the GIL and makes more sense.

Answer (score 3):

Or you could use the Timer class in the threading module:

```
from threading import Timer

def hello():
    print "hello, world"

t = Timer(30.0, hello)
t.start() # after 30 seconds, "hello, world" will be printed
t.cancel() # cancels execution, this only works before the 30 seconds is elapsed
```

This will not start every x seconds, rather it delays the thread for execution in x seconds. But you can still put that in a loop and use t.is_alive() to see its status.

Comment: Where would the loop go?

Comment: That would depend on the use case?

Comment: @Eric, feel free to improve my post if you're not satisfied with it.

Answer (score 3):

A quick followup to [Eric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/102441/eric)'s answer: you can't subclass `Timer` in python 2, since it's actually a light function wrapper around the true class: `_Timer`.  If you do you'll get the issue that pops up in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231427/error-when-calling-the-metaclass-bases-function-argument-1-must-be-code-not).

Using `_Timer` instead fixes it:

```
from threading import _Timer

class RepeatingTimer(_Timer):
    def run(self):
        while not self.finished.is_set():
            self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
            self.finished.wait(self.interval)


t = RepeatingTimer(30.0, self.mqConn.heartbeat_tick)
t.start() # every 30 seconds, call heartbeat_tick

# later
t.cancel() # cancels execution
```

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if `_Timer` was subject to breaking changes through versions, while `Timer` is not (because of the leading prefix "privacy").

I had no issues subclassing `Timer` in 3.7, and the documentation says it's a subclass of `Thread`.

Comment: @Far_Eggs you're likely correct - good comment.  I should've been specific that this was with respect to 2.7.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this would be to use the [circuits](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/circuits) application framework like this:

```
from circuits import Component, Event, Timer


class App(Component):

    def init(self, mqConn):
        self.mqConn = mqConn
        Timer(30, Event.create("heartbeat"), persist=True).register(self)

    def heartbeat(self):
        self.mqConn.heartbeat_tick()


App().run()
```

*Note:* I'm the author of circuits :)

This is just a basic idea and structure -- You would need to adapt this to suit your exact application and requirements!